# Sorting data frame based on month-year time format

Tags: r, sorting, time

I'm struggling with something very basic: sorting a data frame based on a time format (month-year, or, “%B-%y” in this case). My goal is to calculate various monthly statistics, starting with sum.

The part of relevant part of the data frame looks like this * (This goes well and in accordance of my goal. I'm including it here to show where the problem **could** originate from)*:

```
> tmp09
   Instrument AccountValue   monthYear   ExitTime
1         JPM         6997    april-07 2007-04-10
2         JPM         7261      mei-07 2007-05-29
3         JPM         7545     juli-07 2007-07-18
4         JPM         7614     juli-07 2007-07-19
5         JPM         7897 augustus-07 2007-08-22
10        JPM         7423 november-07 2007-11-02
11        KFT         6992      mei-07 2007-05-14
12        KFT         6944      mei-07 2007-05-21
13        KFT         7069     juli-07 2007-07-09
14        KFT         6919     juli-07 2007-07-16
# Order on the exit time, which corresponds with 'monthYear'
> tmp09.sorted <- tmp09[order(tmp09$ExitTime),]
> tmp09.sorted
   Instrument AccountValue   monthYear   ExitTime
1         JPM         6997    april-07 2007-04-10
11        KFT         6992      mei-07 2007-05-14
12        KFT         6944      mei-07 2007-05-21
2         JPM         7261      mei-07 2007-05-29
13        KFT         7069     juli-07 2007-07-09
14        KFT         6919     juli-07 2007-07-16
3         JPM         7545     juli-07 2007-07-18
4         JPM         7614     juli-07 2007-07-19
5         JPM         7897 augustus-07 2007-08-22
10        JPM         7423 november-07 2007-11-02
```

So far, so good, and sorting based on ExitTime works. *The trouble starts when I try to calculate the totals per month, followed by an attempt to sort this output*:

```
# Calculate the total results per month
> Tmp09Totals <- tapply(tmp09.sorted$AccountValue, tmp09.sorted$monthYear, sum)
> Tmp09Totals <- data.frame(Tmp09Totals)
> Tmp09Totals
            Tmp09Totals
april-07           6997
augustus-07        7897
juli-07           29147
mei-07            21197
november-07        7423
```

**How can I sort this output in a chronological Way?**

I've already tried (besides various attempts to convert the monthYear to another date format): order, sort, sort.list, sort_df, reshape, and calculating the sum based on tapply, lapply, sapply, aggregate. And even rewriting the rownames (by giving them a number from 1 to length (`tmp09.sorted2$AccountValue`) didn't work. I also tried to give each month-year a different ID based on what I've learned in another question, but R also experienced difficulties in discriminating between the various month-year values.

The correct order of this output would be `april-07,mei-07,juli-07,augustus07, november-07`:

```
apr-07  6997
mei-07  21197
jul-07  29147
aug-07  7897
nov-07  7423
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be easier to have separate `Month` and `Year` factors, in the correct order, and use `tapply` on the union of both variables, e.g.:

```
## The Month factor
tmp09 <- within(tmp09,
                Month <- droplevels(factor(strftime(ExitTime, format = "%B"),
                                                    levels = month.name)))
## for @Jura25's locale, we can't use the in built English constant
## instead, we can use this solution, from ?month.name:
## format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%B"))
tmp09 <- within(tmp09,
                Month <- droplevels(factor(strftime(ExitTime, format = "%B"),
                                                    levels = format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%B"))))
##
## And the Year factor
tmp09 <- within(tmp09, Year <- factor(strftime(ExitTime, format = "%Y")))
```

Which gives us (in my locale):

```
> head(tmp09)
   Instrument AccountValue   monthYear   ExitTime    Month Year
1         JPM         6997    april-07 2007-04-10    April 2007
2         JPM         7261      mei-07 2007-05-29      May 2007
3         JPM         7545     juli-07 2007-07-18     July 2007
4         JPM         7614     juli-07 2007-07-19     July 2007
5         JPM         7897 augustus-07 2007-08-22   August 2007
10        JPM         7423 november-07 2007-11-02 November 2007
```

Then use `tapply` with both factors:

```
> with(tmp09, tapply(AccountValue, list(Month, Year), sum))
          2007
April     6997
May      21197
July     29147
August    7897
November  7423
```

or via `aggregate`:

```
> with(tmp09, aggregate(AccountValue, list(Month = Month, Year = Year), sum))
     Month Year     x
1    April 2007  6997
2      May 2007 21197
3     July 2007 29147
4   August 2007  7897
5 November 2007  7423
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer Gavin! This worked as I would like it. Especially the aggregate function gives an nice stacked ouput for my various years in the complete data set (and also quite efficient for various calculations). I did receive an error with 'levels = month.name', but after replacing month.name with an custom vector with the month names in my locale, this problem was solved. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Jura25; yes, sorry - those are English months... `?month.name` has this example for month names in your current locale: `format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%B")`, which might save you from typing out the month names each time you want to use them.

Comment: No need to apologize. :) I primarily mentioned it here in case someone else could use it. Thanks for the ISOdate function, I didn't know about it and it is indeed quite handy.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `"yearmon"` class in zoo as it sorts appropriately. Below we create the sample `DF` data frame and then we add a `YearMonth` column of class `"yearmon"` . Finally we perform our aggregation.   The actual processing is just the last two lines (the other part is just to create the sample data frame).

```
Lines <-   "Instrument AccountValue   monthYear   ExitTime
JPM         6997    april-07 2007-04-10
JPM         7261      mei-07 2007-05-29
JPM         7545     juli-07 2007-07-18
JPM         7614     juli-07 2007-07-19
JPM         7897 augustus-07 2007-08-22
JPM         7423 november-07 2007-11-02
KFT         6992      mei-07 2007-05-14
KFT         6944      mei-07 2007-05-21
KFT         7069     juli-07 2007-07-09
KFT         6919     juli-07 2007-07-16"
library(zoo)
DF <- read.table(textConnection(Lines), header = TRUE)

DF$YearMonth <- as.yearmon(DF$ExitTime)
aggregate(AccountValue ~ YearMonth + Instrument, DF, sum)
```

This gives the following:

```
> aggregate(AccountValue ~ YearMonth + Instrument, DF, sum)
  YearMonth Instrument AccountValue
1  Apr 2007        JPM         6997
2  May 2007        JPM         7261
3  Jul 2007        JPM        15159
4  Aug 2007        JPM         7897
5  Nov 2007        JPM         7423
6  May 2007        KFT        13936
7  Jul 2007        KFT        13988
```

A slightly different approach and output uses `read.zoo` directly. It produces one column per instrument and one row per year/month.  We read in the columns assigning them appropriate classes using `"NULL"` for the `monthYear` column since we won't use that one.  We also specify that the time index is the 3rd column of the remaining columns and that we want the input split into columns by the 1st column.  `FUN=as.yearmon` indicates that we want the time index to be converted from `"Date"` class to `"yearmon"` class and we aggregate everything using `sum`.

```
z <- read.zoo(textConnection(Lines),  header = TRUE, index = 3, 
     split = 1, colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "NULL", "Date"),
     FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = sum)
```

The resulting zoo object looks like this:

```
> z
           JPM   KFT
Apr 2007  6997    NA
May 2007  7261 13936
Jul 2007 15159 13988
Aug 2007  7897    NA
Nov 2007  7423    NA
```

We may prefer to keep it as a zoo object to take advantage of other functionality in zoo or we can convert it to a data frame like this: `data.frame(Time = time(z), coredata(z))` which makes the time a separate column or `as.data.frame(z)` which uses row names for the time. `fortify.zoo()z)` also works.

Comment: Thanks G. Grothendieck! I really like the output of the as.yearmon function, which saves me from using multiple columns (year and month) as list, and it gives a nicer output to. I've adopted this into my script to make it more comprehensive. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could reorder factor levels by `reorder` function.

```
tmp09$monthYear <- reorder(tmp09$monthYear, as.numeric(as.Date(tmp09$ExitTime)))
```

Trick is to use numeric representation of date as number of days since 1970-01-01 (see `?Date`) and use mean value of it as reference.

Comment: Thanks Marek, that is indeed quite an efficient way to do it. Sadly, I doesn't work for me. `reorder(tmp09$monthYear, as.numeric(as.Date(tmp09$ExitTime)))
 [1] april-07    mei-07      juli-07     juli-07     augustus-07 november-07
 [7] mei-07      mei-07      juli-07     juli-07`. Perhaps reorder doesn't 'know' my current locale?

Comment: @Jura25 `reorder` doesn't change values but order of levels in factor. You'll see effect when you call `tapply` on the changed data. What do you get if you run `tapply(tmp09.sorted$AccountValue, reorder(tmp09.sorted$monthYear, as.numeric(as.Date(tmp09.sorted$ExitTime))), sum)`?

Comment: Thanks Marek, that did the trick! :) I didn't thought about the function of reorder (instead of sort) thanks for you explaination!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I misunderstood the question at first. Copy the data given in the question first, then

```
> tmp09 <- read.table(file="clipboard", header=TRUE)
> Sys.setlocale(category="LC_TIME", locale="Dutch_Belgium.1252")
[1] "Dutch_Belgium.1252"

# create POSIXlt variable from monthYear
> tmp09$d <- strptime(paste("2007", tmp09$monthYear, sep="-"), "%Y-%B-%d")

# create ordered factor
> tmp09$dFac <- droplevels(cut(tmp09$d, breaks="month", ordered=TRUE))
> tmp09[order(tmp09$d), ]
   Instrument AccountValue   monthYear   ExitTime          d       dFac
1         JPM         6997    april-07 2007-04-10 2007-04-07 2007-04-01
2         JPM         7261      mei-07 2007-05-29 2007-05-07 2007-05-01
11        KFT         6992      mei-07 2007-05-14 2007-05-07 2007-05-01
12        KFT         6944      mei-07 2007-05-21 2007-05-07 2007-05-01
3         JPM         7545     juli-07 2007-07-18 2007-07-07 2007-07-01
4         JPM         7614     juli-07 2007-07-19 2007-07-07 2007-07-01
13        KFT         7069     juli-07 2007-07-09 2007-07-07 2007-07-01
14        KFT         6919     juli-07 2007-07-16 2007-07-07 2007-07-01
5         JPM         7897 augustus-07 2007-08-22 2007-08-07 2007-08-01
10        JPM         7423 november-07 2007-11-02 2007-11-07 2007-11-01

> Tmp09Totals <- tapply(tmp09$AccountValue, tmp09$dFac, sum)
> Tmp09Totals
2007-04-01 2007-05-01 2007-07-01 2007-08-01 2007-11-01 
      6997      21197      29147       7897       7423
```

Comment: thanks for responding. The Sys.setlocale() function is a very good idea, but I'm afraid it didn't matter much. The new column (tmp09$d) has some errors, but sorting on the column ExitTime does work. But I'm especially interested in the sorting of the column Tmp09Totals, which contains the sum of the various months based on the monthYear column. I'm very sorry if my answer wasn't clear enough, I will edit it to better clarify my point. Nonetheless, thanks for responding and suggesting an solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The missing step was to create an ordered factor from the date using `cut()`. I hope this is closer to what you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks Caracal for your answer! It gives indeed the output I was looking for, but with multiple years the paste function gives some trouble with every year as "2007". However, I did learn some useful 'tricks' (such as cut) from your answer, so not all your effort was in vain. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the main problem is how to sort a sequence of Month-Year strings chronologically. The easiest way is to pre-pend a "01" at the beginning of each Month-Year string and sort them as regular dates. So take your final data-frame Tmp09Totals, and do this:

```
monYear <- rownames(Tmp09Totals)
sortedMonYear <- format(sort( as.Date( paste('01-', monYear, sep = ''),
                                       '%d-%B-%y')), 
                       '%B-%y')
Tmp09Totals[ sortedMonYear, , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: But you don't need *any* of this if you get your factors in the correct order in the first place. You answer reorders the output. If you don't get the input in logical order, however, you have to reorder every output you produce from these data.

Comment: Thanks for responding Prasad. It looks somewhat complicated, but I just tested it, and it works good (even with multiple years). I really like your innovate way to paste '01' before the 'monthYear' in order to be able to convert it to a regular date. Good point to remember in my futher R adventures. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An old post but worthy of a `data.table` approach:

Read in data and set local as described by @caracal

```
> Sys.setlocale(category="LC_TIME", locale="Dutch_Belgium.1252")
[1] "Dutch_Belgium.1252"
> tmp09 <- read.table(file="clipboard", header=TRUE)
> tmp09$ExitTime <- as.Date(tmp09$ExitTime)
```

Summarise data as requested

```
require(data.table)
> data.table(tmp09)[, 
+                   .(Tmp09Total = sum(AccountValue)),
+                   by = .(Date = format(ExitTime, "%B-%y"))]
          Date Tmp09Total
1:    april-07       6997
2:      mei-07      21197
3:     juli-07      29147
4: augustus-07       7897
5: november-07       7423
```