# R factor - time series conversion not working

Tags: r, datetime

I have the common problem of converting a factor of the format:

```
"2007/01"
```

to time series object. The data can be found here: http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=prc_hicp_midx&lang=en
I did  replace the "M" in YYYY"M"MM with a "/".

```
> str(infl)
'data.frame':   3560 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ TIME    : Factor w/ 89 levels "2007/01","2007/02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ GEO     : Factor w/ 40 levels "Austria","Belgium",..: 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 ...
 $ INFOTYPE: Factor w/ 1 level "Index, 2005=100": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ COICOP  : Factor w/ 1 level "All-items HICP": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Value   : Factor w/ 1952 levels ":","100.49","100.5",..: 35 51 85 112 127 131 120 126 147 169 ...
```

I followed all the different approaches:

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(infl$TIME), format = "%Y/%m") 
as.POSIXlt(as.character(infl$TIME), format = "%Y/%m")
as.Date(as.character(infl$TIME), format = "%Y/%m")
```

However all of them return "NA" for the entire length of the series. Has anyone any idea why I cannot convert this series to a ts object?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be a problem converting between dates with just year and month using the relevant functions!

    `> as.Date("2007/01",format="%Y/%b")
    [1] NA
    > as.Date("2007/01/01",format="%Y/%m/%d")
    [1] "2007-01-01"`

Comment: Exactly, I was a bit puzzeled at first at what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can make it work using the `yearmon` object from the `zoo package`:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon("2007/01", "%Y/%m")
# [1] "Jan 2007"
```

See [Sorting an data frame based on month-year time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592455/sorting-an-data-frame-based-on-month-year-time-format) for more ideas.